# Override the results of Search API pages module

Tags: search

I have disabled the default search and enable module 'Search API' and Search API SOLR(used for Backend) to perform search in Drupal 9. I have also enabled Search API pages module and created a search page through this module.

Search API pages module has 2 twigs in folder templates. I have overridden both and when
I make a change in search-api-page.html.twig I see difference in the search page but when I make
a change in search-api-page-result.html.twig I see no difference.

I want to customize the appearance of search results.